# Nautilus open terminal in remote edit command

Tags: nautilus, configuration, remote

I regularly use the "right click → open in remote terminal" functionality of Nautilus in Ubuntu 22.04. I don't know the command, but it seems it is doing `ssh blah@host`, and I would like to add the `-X` flag so I can open GUI applications from this terminal. How can I modify it?

Comment: Instead of trying to modifying that, you could modify your `~/.ssh/config` to add `ForwardX11Trusted yes` for `Hostname host`. That will be much simpler to accomplish

Comment: How can I do this? I create the `config` file and what should I write in it? Feel free to cast your comment into an answer, so I can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to modifying that, you could modify your `~/.ssh/config` to enabled `ForwardX11` (the config file equivalent of `-X`) for that host. That will be much simpler to accomplish. For clarity, I'm going to use `blah@some-server` instead of `blah@host`.

Edit `~/.ssh/config`, and add:

```
Host some-server
    ForwardX11 yes
```

(The indentation is optional, but it makes it easier to understand long config files.)

If you want to specifically match the combination of user `blah` and server `some-server`, then use `Match` instead (as suggested by [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691217/70524)):

```
Match Host some-server User blah
    ForwardX11 yes
```

Comment: I still cannot make it work. I wrote `Host ip_addres`. Do I have to restart something before it works?

Comment: @user171780 whatever comes after `Host` should exactly match whatever hostname/IP Nautilus uses to connect - so if Nautilus connects to `ip_addres`, then put that, or if it connects to `some-server.fqdn`, put that. No restarts should be needed.

Comment: I think you may need to enable `ForwardX11` rather than / as well as `ForwardX11Trusted`? (iirc the former implies the latter, at least in Debian-derived configurations)

Comment: Indeed, replacing `ForwardX11Trusted` with `ForwardX11` in the `~/.ssh/config` file does what I want. Thanks. @muru please update your answer.

Comment: @user171780 can you update your question to use `-X` then, because that is the equivalent of `ForwardX11`

Comment: I have updated the question.